# Why can’t I share my Internet connection with another Mac?

Tags: macos, sharing, internet

I tried to share my Internet connection with another Mac but it failed. I could before I upgraded to Mountain Lion.

I have a 3G USB modem that I use for Internet. I went to *System Preferences* → *Sharing* → *Internet Sharing* → Select my 3G device from *Share your connection from* → Tick *WI-FI* → Setup *WI-FI Options...* and then enable Internet sharing.

However, the other Mac can see my network but cannot join.

How do I fix this?

HW: MacBook Pro Retina 15"
OS: Mountain Lion

[image]

Comment: How near are the machines - the graphic shows that the WiFi signal is too weak, the arcs turn black showing signal strength

Answer (score 2):

You could try disabling your Wi-Fi, changing the sharing settings so that the security is off (just for testing purposes of course) then enabling your Wi-Fi and try again.